# How to disable OpenFileDialog opening files automatically?

Tags: c#

I am using following code to select a file to import in a Windows Forms project.

```
OpenFileDialog fdlg = new OpenFileDialog();
fdlg.Title = "C# Corner Open File Dialog";
fdlg.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";
fdlg.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|All files (*.*)|*.*";
fdlg.FilterIndex = 2;
fdlg.RestoreDirectory = true;
if (fdlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    txtpath.Text = fdlg.FileName;
}
```

The problem is that the selected file is opened in the background which I don't want. What can I do to just get the path of selected file without opening it?

Comment: That code doesn't open the file in my tests... could you show a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Which files are you trying to open? It behaves differently for System folders.. e.g. If you open a Windows/Fonts folder using.. OpenFileDialog it will open file in Fonts Viewer.. and not select the file...

Comment: I am selecting .xls file and then importing sheet using oledb connectionstring.
can there be any problem with that?

Comment: "but the selected file gets open in the background which I don't want." : How do you know this? What method are you using to see which files are opened and when they were opened?

Comment: when I close my application the excel file gets opened.
I am using excel file on shared network

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Showing an [`OpenFileDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx) and the user selecting a file does not open the file. The file can be opened by calling [`OpenFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.openfile.aspx). In the code you posted the file is not opened. That code appears to be copied from an example on MSDN. The rest of the code from that example is here:

```
if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    try
    {
        if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)  // File is opened here.
        {
            using (myStream)
            {
                // Insert code to read the stream here.
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " +
                        ex.Message);
    }
}
```

If the file is being opened when you don't want it opened then the problem must be somewhere else and not in the code you posted. It is possible for example that you have not closed the file (for example by using Dispose) after you finished using it last time.

Comment: I have closed the connection after using it.

Comment: This is long time gone, but for the sake of completeness, the FileOpenDialog checks the state of the file and _does_ in fact produce an error if the file is already in use, even if it doesn't actually open the file. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22342651/how-to-select-the-file-which-is-already-opened-using-openfiledialog