# How to select the file which is already opened using OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I am trying to select the file which is already opened in quickbook software.

code :

```
 OpenFileDialog ofdBrowseVInv = new OpenFileDialog();

            ofdBrowseVInv.Title = "Locate QuickBook Company File";
            ofdBrowseVInv.Filter = "QuickBook Company File (*.qbw,*.qbw)|*.qbw;*.qbm";
            ofdBrowseVInv.FileName = "";


           if (ofdBrowseVInv.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string strfilename = ofdBrowseVInv.InitialDirectory + ofdBrowseVInv.FileName;

            }
```

After selecting the file .. i am getting message : **File in use**

can any one tell me how can i select the file which is already opened...

[image: File in use Screen shot]

Comment: The code you have shared will not produce File in use error message, because you are only reading the filename till this point. I believe you are trying to open the file afterwards causing the error.

Comment: After selecting the file from ShowDiloag... i am getting message...

Comment: Instead of .QBW file if i use .xslx it is working....even if .xslx file open...

Comment: Is the file open for shared read? Otherwise, there wouldn't be anything you can do about that file, so maybe that's why the dialog prevents you from selecting it.

Answer (score 11):

The following code seems to help:

```
ofdBrowseVInv.ValidateNames = false;
```

see more here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/56fbbf9b-31d5-4e89-be85-83d9cb1d538c/openfiledialog-this-file-is-in-use?forum=netfxbcl

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me perfectly.

```
ofdBrowseVInv.ValidateNames = false;
```